# What risks in deploying .NET Framework 4.0?

Tags: security, .net-4.0, xbap

I'm developing tools for a WPF clickonce XBAP application for internal deployment within a large corporation.  I'd really like to use Expression Blend 4, but that requires me to upgrade to .NET 4.0 (right?).

The project manager tells me the corporate IT department likely won't roll out .NET 4.0 framework to desktops until late 2011.

Is there any basis for their security concerns?

Does anyone know of any resources that I could point them to to allay their fears?

If I upgrade to .NET 4.0 Client profile, could they just roll out a smaller (and presumably more secure) framework?

**Update:** Also, they may be worried about breaking existing applications.  What is the risk that existing apps that use 3.5 (or earlier) will be impacted by having 4.0 installed?

Comment: Did they *say* it was due to security concerns? Sometimes they just want to do compatibility tests with existing software, and sometimes that takes a lot of time (especially if only 1 or 2 people are responsible and only part-time or there's a large amount of testing).

Comment: I thought existing software wouldn't be impacted since it would continue to use whatever framework is currently in use.  Is this not true?

Comment: Could you write this using Silverlight, so you just have to upgrade one server?

Comment: Why would you have to update a server to use Silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe blend 4 will still work with .Net 3.5 projects. There should be no security concerns for desktops, especially if you stick to the Client version of the framework.

Comment: They want to use WPF xbap clickonce.  When I try to open the 3.5 project with Expression Blend 4, it complains.  Is there some trick to doing this?

Comment: What is complaint does blend display? and are the projects for VS2008 or VS2010?

Comment: Turns out it didn't like something in the 3.5 project, but I can indeed create a new project with Blend 4 that points to the 3.5 .NET framework.